# ATG customized repository

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet, atg-dust

How to create a customized repository in ATG with certain fields like name id and so on. And how to query the same information according to name ID or any other fields.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create testRepository.xml at some path in config (e.g. /com/myproject/content/testRepository.xml) having item descriptor with all custom table.
2. Create testRepository.properties at same path as -

> $class=atg.adapter.gsa.GSARepository
>       $scope=global
>       XMLToolsFactory=/atg/dynamo/service/xml/XMLToolsFactory
>       dataSource=/atg/dynamo/service/jdbc/SwitchingDataSource
>       definitionFiles=/com/myproject/content/testRepository.xml
>       groupContainerPath=/atg/registry/RepositoryGroups
>       idGenerator=/atg/dynamo/service/IdGenerator
>       lockManager=/atg/dynamo/service/ClientLockManager
>       repositoryName=Test Repository
>       transactionManager=/atg/dynamo/transaction/TransactionManager

3. Now you can refer this component in your droplet or form handler as -

   testRepository=/com/myproject/content/testRepository
4. create setter and getter for the same in java.
5. Now you can query as -

> ```
> private RepositoryItem[] getMyTestItems() {
> RepositoryItem[] testItems = null;
> try {
> RepositoryView repView = getTestRepository().getView("myItemDescriptor");
> RqlStatement statement = getRqlQuery(); //your query that can be defined in property file
> Object params[] = new Object[1];
> params[0] = "anyParam";
>
> testItems = statement.executeQuery(repView, params);
> } catch (RepositoryException ex) {
> vlogDebug("testItems{0} ", ex);
> } finally {
> LoadingStrategyContext.popLoadStrategy();
> }
> return testItems;
> }
> ```